# Создание папки в /home

Tags: php

Сайт находится в `/home/www/site.ru`. Как мне с помощью PHP создать папку в `/home`?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать функцию [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mkdir.php).

Comment: Not work уже пробывал

Comment: Каков результат выполнения функции? Какое сообщение об ошибке имело место быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если отвечать буквально, то с помощью функции mkdir() или вызвав внешнюю команду, например так

```
exec('mkdir /home/newdir');
```

Но вы вероятно имели в виду PHP который работает из-под веб-сервера и обладает полномочиями пользователя `www-data`. Для него **прав на /home/ скорее всего не хватит**. Сначала измените права на /home/ или как-то переосмыслите задачу.

Answer (score 2):

По умолчании в `/home` папки может создавать только *root*. Вам надо либо изменить права на запись папки, либо выдать права пользователю под которым выполняется ваш скрипт.

Comment: Полностью согласен, одна оговорка, если пользователь работает на стороннем хосте то не факт что у него вообще есть возможность управлять правами пользователей, в данном случае удобнее перейти на VPS/VDS сервер, на нем уж точно будут все права.

Comment: в /home директории юзеру по дефолту соответствует. Думаю не стоит нарушать это соглашение и создать юзера для сайта.